# Showing $\Gamma(\alpha\times\alpha)\leq\omega^\alpha$.

Tags: set-theory, well-orders

I'm trying to prove Exercise 3.5 in Set Theory by Thomas Jech:
$$
\Gamma(\alpha\times\alpha) \leq \omega^\alpha
$$
where $\Gamma(\alpha\times\beta)=\operatorname{otp}(\{(\zeta,\delta)\mid(\zeta,\delta)\lt(\alpha\times\beta)\})$ 
and 
$$(\zeta,\delta)\lt(\alpha,\beta) \iff
\begin{cases}
  \max(\zeta,\delta)\lt \max(\alpha,\beta)\\    
  \max(\zeta,\delta)= \max(\alpha,\beta)\text{ and } \zeta\lt\alpha\\
  \max(\zeta,\delta)= \max(\alpha,\beta)\text{ and } \zeta=\alpha \text{ and }\delta\lt\beta
\end{cases}$$
Here's what I've tried so far:

- If $\alpha=0$ , then $\Gamma(\alpha\times\alpha) = 0\le1=\omega^0$.
- If $\alpha>0$ is finite, then $\Gamma(\alpha\times\alpha)$ is also finite, hence $\Gamma(\alpha\times\alpha) \lt \omega \le\omega^\alpha$.

Then I'm not too sure where to go from here

Comment: What you've written doesn't make much sense. In most instances, when you write $\alpha \times\beta,$ it should be $(\alpha,\beta).$

Comment: I don't have the Jech book.  Are we using ordinal exponentiation here?

Comment: Aren't they the same spaceisdarkgreen? It is ordinal exponentiation Robert Shore.

Comment: @Nadroj No, not at all.

Comment: You are absolutely right, thank you Spaceisdarkgreen